# Prove continuity/discontinuity of the Popcorn Function (Thomae's Function).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I have to prove that a function $f:]0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ :
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac1q,  & \text{if $x \in \Bbb Q$  with $ x=\frac{p}q$ for $p,q \in \Bbb N$ coprime} \\
0, & \text{if $x \notin \Bbb Q $}
\end{cases}
$$

is discontinuous in every point $x \in \ ]0,1] \cap\Bbb Q$.

And then to consider $x \in \ ]0,1] \backslash \Bbb Q$ and prove that it is continuous.

For now I learned different ways to prove continuity (epsilon-delta, sequences), but I'm never sure what would be better to use in each different case.

I wanted to prove the discontinuity by using sequences:
$$\forall x_n \quad x_n\rightarrow a \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(x_n) \rightarrow f(a)$$

I tried creating a sequence $ x_n=\frac1n + a$, we know it converges to $a$ but $f(x_n)\ $ doesn't  converges to $\ f(a)$ because there would still be some points not in our set (irrational numbers that creates gaps).

But I don't think it works, so I'm asking you if you could help me solving the two questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sometimes called the **Popcorn Function**, since if you look at a picture of the graph, it looks like kernels of popcorn popping. (Also called the **Thomae's Function**.)

To prove it is **discontinuous at any rational point**, you could argue in the following way: Since the irrationals that are in $(0,1)$ are dense in $(0,1)$, given any rational number $p/q$ in $(0,1)$, we know $f(p/q) = 1/q$.  But let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $p/q$ (by the definition of density).  Then $\lim \limits_{a_{n} \to (p/q)} f(x) = 0 \neq f(p/q)$.  Thus, $f$ fails to be continuous at $x = p/q$.

Now, to prove it is **continuous at every irrational point**, I recommend you do it in the following way:

1. Prove that for each irrational number $x \in (0,1)$, given $N \in \Bbb N$, we can find $\delta_{N} > 0$ so that the rational numbers in $(x - \delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$ all have denominator larger than $N$.
2. Once you have the result from above, we can use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity to prove $f$ is continuous at each irrational point.

So, first prove 1. (It's not too hard.) Once you've done that, you can accomplish 2. in the following way:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $x \in (0,1)$ be irrational.  Choose $N$ so that $\frac{1}{n} \leq \epsilon$ for every $n \geq N$ (by the archimedian property).
>
> By what you proved in 1., find $\delta_{N} > 0$ so that $(x - \delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$ contains rational numbers only with denominators larger than $N$.
>
> Then if $y \in (x-\delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$, $y$ could either be rational or irrational.  If $y$ is irrational, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = |0 - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$ (since $f(z) = 0$ if $z$ is irrational).
>
> On the other hand, if $y$ is rational, we have $y = p/q$ with $q \geq N$.  So $|f(x) - f(y)| = |0 - f(y)| = |f(y)| = |1/q| \leq |1/N| < \epsilon$, and this is true for every $y \in (x-\delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$.
>
> Thus, given any $\epsilon > 0$, if $x \in (0,1)$ is irrational, we found $\delta > 0$ (which was actually $\delta_{N}$ in the proof) so that $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't really understand the first part about the density (which would be the definition?). And how you get the limit?

Comment: @Ergo One way to think about density is this: We say a subset $A$ of $X$ is *dense* in $X$ if for every element of $X$, we can find a sequence of elements in $A$ that converge to $X$.  So when I say the rationals that are in $(0,1)$ are dense in $(0,1)$, I mean for every element of $(0,1)$, we can find a sequence of rational numbers that converges to that element.  I will write how I got the limit in a bit, as I have to run off for now.

Comment: @Ergo I misspoke in my last comment.  It's true that the rationals in $(0,1)$ are dense in $(0,1)$, and so are the irrationals in $(0,1)$.  But we only needed to use that the irrationals are dense, as is used in my actual answer.  Now, to explain the limit:  We let $p/q$ be a rational number in $(0,1)$ and $a_{n}$ be a sequence of irrational numbers in $(0,1)$ converging to $p/q$ (which we can find since irrationals are dense).  We know if $f$ were continuous at $p/q$, then it must be true that $\lim \limits_{x \to (p/q)} f(x) = f(p/q) = 1/q$.

Comment: @Ergo But let's look at the limit along the sequence $a_{n}$.  Since the $a_{n}$ are irrational, for each $n$, $f(a_{n}) = 0$ by the definition of $f$.  Now, $\lim \limits_{a_{n} \to (p/q)} f(x) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(a_{n}) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$.  But this does not equal $f(p/q) = 1/q$, so that means $f$ is not continuous at $p/q$.

Comment: @layman good answer, thank you! How does one prove 1), or at least why is it heuristically true?

Comment: @Daniele1234 The idea is really simple.  Let $x$ be an irrational number.  For each $n$, we can think of all the possible positive rational numbers with denominator $n$: $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{2}{n}$, $\frac{3}{n}$, \frac{4}{n}$, \frac{5}{n}$, $\dots$.  Since $x$ is irrational, it is not equal to any of these, but it is between two consecutive ones, say, $(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n})$, and obviously we can find a positive $\epsilon_{n}>0$ so that $(x - \epsilon_{n}, x + \epsilon_{n}) \subseteq (\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n})$ (just draw a picture to see this).  So...

Comment: @Daniele1234 $(x - \epsilon_{n}, x + \epsilon_{n})$ doesn't have any rational numbers with denominator $n$ in them by the way we choose $n$ (listing all rational numbers out with denominator $n$, finding two consecutive ones that $x$ is between, and taking $\epsilon_{n}$ so that the interval doesn't contain these two, and so doesn't contain any of the rationals with denominator $n$).  Now do this again for $n-1$, i.e., find $\epsilon_{n-1}$ in the same way to exclude rationals with denominator $n-1$.  And find $\epsilon_{n-2}$ to exclude the denominator $n-2$.  And...

Comment: @Daniele1234 find $\epsilon_{n-3}$, $\epsilon_{n-4}$, $\epsilon_{n-5}$, $\dots$, $\epsilon_{2}$, $\epsilon_{1}$.  Each of these $\epsilon_{i}$'s creates an interval around $x$ that excludes all rationals with denominator $i$.  Then take $\epsilon := \min \limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \{ \epsilon_{i} \}$, and this $\epsilon$ creates an interval around $x$ that excludes all rationals with denominator $1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$, $n-1$, $n$.  So we found an interval around $x$ that excludes all rationals with denominator less than or equal to $n$.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Whether the discontinuity at rational points is removable discontinuity ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of proving it by choosing an appropriate sequence is viable, but it becomes easier if you define a sequence (still converging to a) where the individual members are irrational.

For the second part sequences are clumsy because, in order to prove continuity, you would have to consider *every* possible sequence. You need to show that any fraction that is sufficiently close to a given irrational number a has a large simplest denominator.