# Proof Irrational number $x$, given $N\in{\mathbb{N}}$ exists $\epsilon>0$ so all rationals $\in{V_\epsilon{(x)}}$ have denominator larger than N.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am trying to show that Thomae's function is continuous at every irrational point (I have already shown discontinuous at every rational point), and for that - following this answer [Prove continuity/discontinuity of the Popcorn Function (Thomae's Function).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547668/prove-continuity-discontinuity-of-the-popcorn-function-thomaes-function) - I would like to show that for an irrational number $x$, given $N\in{\mathbb{N}}$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that all rationals $\in{V_\epsilon{(x)}}$ have denominator larger than N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are only finitely many rational points in $[0,1]$ whose denominator is *not* larger than $N$ there has to be a $\varepsilon$ so small that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ contains none of them; just take$$\varepsilon=\min\{|x-y|\,:\,y\text{ is rational and its denominator is}\leqslant N\}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to show this for the whole domain of the reals for Thomae's function, so is there a way to show this for any irrational $x$?

Comment: @Daniele1234 Sure. Start by taking $\varepsilon<1$. In the interval $(x-1,x+1)$ there are only finitely finitely many rational nmbers in whose denominator is not larger than $N$. Now, you can do as I did in my answer.