# Is $f(x)$ continuous at irrational points here?

Tags: calculus, continuity, contest-math

**Question:**

$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&;& x\text{ is irrational}\\\frac1n&;& x\text{ is rational of the form } x=\frac mn\text{ in lowest terms with } m,n\gt0\end{cases}$

Which of the the following is/are correct?

A) $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1$

B) $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=2$

C) $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=\sqrt2$

D) $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=\sqrt3$

**Attempt:**

The answer given is AB and the solution just says $f(x)$ is continuous at all irrational points.

First, I think there is a typo in question. Instead of $\frac1n$, maybe there should be $\frac1x$. But I am not sure.

Because even with $\frac1x$, I am not sure how $f(x)$ would be continuous at irrational points.

Say, $x=√2$, then $f(x)$ is zero there but on its left and right, it's not zero. So, it's not continuous there, right?

If we have to change the question statement with minimum number of changes to ensure that $f(x)$ is continuous at irrational points and discontinuous at rational points then what could be those changes? Is just changing $n$ to $x$ enough?

Comment: Look up Thomae’s function and any of the many duplicates on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[[ It seems that this is a Duplicate Question , I am giving "Simple Intuitive Way" to go over it ]]**

Continuity is usually given like "Limit at $x=a$ is $f(a)$" , hence we can try to use that with this Case.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x) = \lim_{m/n \rightarrow 1} f(m/n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(1 \pm 1/n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n = 0$ , that is , limit is Zero.
$f(1)=1$
**Not Continuous**

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f(x) = \lim_{m/n \rightarrow 2} f(m/n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(2 \pm 1/n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n = 0$ , that is , limit is Zero.
$f(2)=1$
**Not Continuous**

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{2}} f(x) = 0$ , since every neighborhood of $\sqrt{2}$ has irrational numbers : limit is finite.
$f(\sqrt{2})=0$
**Continuous**

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}} f(x) = 0$ , since every neighborhood of $\sqrt{3}$ has irrational numbers : limit is finite.
$f(\sqrt{3})=0$
**Continuous**

Answer (score 1):

The correct answers are A and B.

The function in question is in fact [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). Now we can prove that it is discontinuous at any rational point and continuous at any irrational point.

##### Proof that Thomae's function is discontinuous at any rational point:

> Since the irrationals that are in $(0,1)$ are dense in $(0,1)$, given any rational number $p/q$ in $(0,1)$, we know $f(p/q) = 1/q$.  But let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $p/q$ (by the definition of density).  Then $\lim \limits_{a_{n} \to (p/q)} f(x) = 0 \neq f(p/q)$.  Thus, $f$ fails to be continuous at $x = p/q$.

##### Proof that Thomae's function is continuous at any irrational point:

> 1. Prove that for each irrational number $x \in (0,1)$, given $N \in \Bbb N$, we can find $\delta_{N} > 0$ so that the rational numbers in $(x - \delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$ all have denominator larger than $N$.
> 2. Once you have the result from above, we can use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity to prove $f$ is continuous at each irrational point.
>
> So, first prove 1. (It's not too hard.) Once you've done that, you can accomplish 2. in the following way:
>
> Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $x \in (0,1)$ be irrational.  Choose $N$ so that $\frac{1}{n} \leq \epsilon$ for every $n \geq N$ (by the archimedian property).
>
> By what you proved in 1., find $\delta_{N} > 0$ so that $(x - \delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$ contains rational numbers only with denominators larger than $N$.
>
> Then if $y \in (x-\delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$, $y$ could either be rational or irrational.  If $y$ is irrational, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = |0 - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$ (since $f(z) = 0$ if $z$ is irrational).
>
> On the other hand, if $y$ is rational, we have $y = p/q$ with $q \geq N$.  So $|f(x) - f(y)| = |0 - f(y)| = |f(y)| = |1/q| \leq |1/N| < \epsilon$, and this is true for every $y \in (x-\delta_{N}, x + \delta_{N})$.
>
> Thus, given any $\epsilon > 0$, if $x \in (0,1)$ is irrational, we found $\delta > 0$ (which was actually $\delta_{N}$ in the proof) so that $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Both answers taken from [Prove continuity/discontinuity of the Popcorn Function (Thomae's Function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547668/prove-continuity-discontinuity-of-the-popcorn-function-thomaes-function).

Comment: Please avoid answering duplicates.